# how to select (in jquery) the nth child div when other child elements also exist

Tags: jquery

I have something like the following html:

```
<div id="foo">
  <div>...</div>
  <p>...</p>
  <div>...</div>
  <p>...</p>
  <hr />
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
</div>
```

In between each sub div of "foo" there are zero or more other elements.  I want to be able to select the nth sub div of foo.

nth-child includes the other elements.  For example:

```
$("#foo:nth-child(2)")
```

gives me the first p tag instead of the second div.

Comment: use the [nth-type-of](http://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/) filter

Comment: `nth-child` gives `children` of div... use `:nth-of-type(n)` or `:eq(n)`

Comment: @ArunPJohny Your link's text has confused me initially... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your jquery would be

```
$("#foo").find('div:eq(1)')
```

for more specific, if child contain another div too, then you will have to use child selector.

```
$("#foo > div:eq(1)")
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/y4Z5Q/2/)

Comment: @Graham: yes it is zero based.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`:nth-of-type(n)`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-of-type-selector/) here,

```
$("#foo > div:nth-of-type(2)")
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/KDLUe/)

Comment: This works too. Amit's makes more sense to me though

Comment: @Graham More sense..?!? :O  ok.. Its completely your wish..! :)

Comment: @Graham: both the code are same.  " > " sign is used to select child element not sub child . by using this sign , you will get only child element not sub child.

Comment: yes I know - its subjective, but each to their own :-)

Comment: @Graham I always prefer expert's opinion.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24778430/how-to-select-in-jquery-the-nth-child-div-when-other-child-elements-also-exist/24778495?noredirect=1#comment38451639_24778430 and  I don't know about your thought in this..

Comment: Good point Amit - your solution does not work if one of the sub divs has sub divs of its own